# how to get checkbox+label series to stack vertically while filling available width?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I have a project that uses Bootstrap 4. In one form, I have a checkbox for each state in the U.S. plus a few territories. These label/checkbox pairs display inline, filling to utilize available width on a large screen, which is good. **However**, each state appears on the same line as though they were words like so:

```
☐ Alabama  ☐ Alaska  ☐ Arizona  ☐ Arkansas  ☐ California
☐ Colorado  ☐ Connecticut etc etc
```

I want instead for each subsequent checkbox to display vertically on the next line but wrapping into columns to fill the available space on a large screen. I.e., on a phone (a small screen) there might be only one state per line, but on a large screen, you'd get multiple columns like so:

```
☐ Alabama       ☐ Maryland      ☐ Rhode Island
☐ Alaska        ☐ Massachusetts ☐ South Carolina
☐ Arizona       ☐ Michigan      ☐ South Dakota
☐ Arkansas      ☐ Minnesota     ☐ Tennessee
☐ California    ☐ Mississippi   ☐ Texas
☐ Colorado      ☐ Missouri      ☐ Utah
☐ Connecticut   ☐ Montana       ☐ Vermont
☐ Delaware      ☐ Nebraska      ☐ Virginia
☐ Florida       ☐ Nevada        ☐ Washington
☐ Georgia       ☐ New Hampshire ☐ West Virginia
☐ Hawaii        ☐ New Jersey    ☐ Wisconsin
☐ Idaho         ☐ New Mexico    ☐ Wyoming
☐ Illinois      ☐ New York      ☐ American Somoa
☐ Indiana       ☐ North Carolina☐ Federated Micronesia
☐ Iowa          ☐ North Dakota  ☐ Guam
☐ Kansas        ☐ Ohio          ☐ Marshall Islands
☐ Kentucky      ☐ Oklahoma      ☐ Puerto Rico
☐ Louisiana     ☐ Oregon        ☐ U.S. Virgin Islands
☐ Maine         ☐ Pennsylvania  ☐ Washington, D.C.
```

Here's a sample of my current HTML markup:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h3 class="card-title">State:</h3>
                    <div class="card-text">
                        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="state_nopref" value="state_nopref" onclick="uncheck_all_state(this)" checked>No Preference
                            </label>
                        </div><!-- end checkbox -->
                        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                            <label>
                                <input name="state[]" type="checkbox" value="AL" onclick="uncheck_state_nopref(this)" >Alabama
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                            <label>
                                <input name="state[]" type="checkbox" value="AK" onclick="uncheck_state_nopref(this)" >Alaska
                            </label>
                        </div>

<!-- ETC -->
                        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                            <label>
                                <input name="state[]" type="checkbox" value="VI" onclick="uncheck_state_nopref(this)" >U.S. Virgin Islands
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                            <label>
                                <input name="state[]" type="checkbox" value="DC" onclick="uncheck_state_nopref(this)" >Washington, D.C.
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- end card-text -->
                </div>
            </div><!-- end card -->
        </div><!-- end column -->
    </div><!-- end row -->
</div>
```

Is there some simple way to have my layout take advantage of the extra width of large screens by displaying in additional columns?

Answer (score 1):

```css
.form-check.form-check-inline {
    width: 33%;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h3 class="card-title">State:</h3>
                    <div class="card-text">
                        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="state_nopref" value="state_nopref" onclick="uncheck_all_state(this)" checked>No Preference
                            </label>
                        </div><!-- end checkbox -->
                        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                            <label>
                                <input name="state[]" type="checkbox" value="AL" onclick="uncheck_state_nopref(this)" >Alabama
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                            <label>
                                <input name="state[]" type="checkbox" value="AK" onclick="uncheck_state_nopref(this)" >Alaska
                            </label>
                        </div>

<!-- ETC -->
                        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                            <label>
                                <input name="state[]" type="checkbox" value="VI" onclick="uncheck_state_nopref(this)" >U.S. Virgin Islands
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                            <label>
                                <input name="state[]" type="checkbox" value="DC" onclick="uncheck_state_nopref(this)" >Washington, D.C.
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- end card-text -->
                </div>
            </div><!-- end card -->
        </div><!-- end column -->
    </div><!-- end row -->
</div>
```

This can also work.

Comment: This answer seems to work well, but experiences some text overlap and weirdness when I make the window very narrow. This weirdness can be prevented by adding `min-width: 175px;` to your style definition and then it appears to work quite nicely. I'm upvoting your answer. If you add the `min-width` directive, I'll select this as the answer.

Comment: oh dang i just realized the checkboxes go left-to-right first instead of top-to-bottom. The columns are nice and tidy, but the order of the listed elements is wrong.

Comment: Yes. If you are wanting the order to go top to bottom then you are bound to set the column height (like first example).

Comment: Surely there must be a way to have the browser display downward first, but opportunistically create additional columns to fill available horizontal space?

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
    padding: 20px;
}

.w-10 {
    width: 100%;
}

.myGroup {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    height: 300px !important;
}
```

```html
<loadcss/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 w-10">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h3 class="card-title">State:</h3>
                    <div class="card-text myGroup">
                        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="state_nopref" value="state_nopref" onclick="uncheck_all_state(this)" checked>No Preference
                            </label>
                        </div><!-- end checkbox -->
                        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                            <label>
                                <input name="state[]" type="checkbox" value="AL" onclick="uncheck_state_nopref(this)" >Alabama
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                            <label>
                                <input name="state[]" type="checkbox" value="AK" onclick="uncheck_state_nopref(this)" >Alaska
                            </label>
                        </div>

<!-- ETC -->
                        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                            <label>
                                <input name="state[]" type="checkbox" value="VI" onclick="uncheck_state_nopref(this)" >U.S. Virgin Islands
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                            <label>
                                <input name="state[]" type="checkbox" value="DC" onclick="uncheck_state_nopref(this)" >Washington, D.C.
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="state_nopref" value="state_nopref" onclick="uncheck_all_state(this)" checked>No Preference
                            </label>
                        </div><!-- end checkbox -->
                        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                            <label>
                                <input name="state[]" type="checkbox" value="AL" onclick="uncheck_state_nopref(this)" >Alabama
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                            <label>
                                <input name="state[]" type="checkbox" value="AK" onclick="uncheck_state_nopref(this)" >Alaska
                            </label>
                        </div>

<!-- ETC -->
                        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                            <label>
                                <input name="state[]" type="checkbox" value="VI" onclick="uncheck_state_nopref(this)" >U.S. Virgin Islands
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                            <label>
                                <input name="state[]" type="checkbox" value="DC" onclick="uncheck_state_nopref(this)" >Washington, D.C.
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="state_nopref" value="state_nopref" onclick="uncheck_all_state(this)" checked>No Preference
                            </label>
                        </div><!-- end checkbox -->
                        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                            <label>
                                <input name="state[]" type="checkbox" value="AL" onclick="uncheck_state_nopref(this)" >Alabama
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                            <label>
                                <input name="state[]" type="checkbox" value="AK" onclick="uncheck_state_nopref(this)" >Alaska
                            </label>
                        </div>

<!-- ETC -->
                        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                            <label>
                                <input name="state[]" type="checkbox" value="VI" onclick="uncheck_state_nopref(this)" >U.S. Virgin Islands
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                            <label>
                                <input name="state[]" type="checkbox" value="DC" onclick="uncheck_state_nopref(this)" >Washington, D.C.
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="state_nopref" value="state_nopref" onclick="uncheck_all_state(this)" checked>No Preference
                            </label>
                        </div><!-- end checkbox -->
                        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                            <label>
                                <input name="state[]" type="checkbox" value="AL" onclick="uncheck_state_nopref(this)" >Alabama
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                            <label>
                                <input name="state[]" type="checkbox" value="AK" onclick="uncheck_state_nopref(this)" >Alaska
                            </label>
                        </div>

<!-- ETC -->
                        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                            <label>
                                <input name="state[]" type="checkbox" value="VI" onclick="uncheck_state_nopref(this)" >U.S. Virgin Islands
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                            <label>
                                <input name="state[]" type="checkbox" value="DC" onclick="uncheck_state_nopref(this)" >Washington, D.C.
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- end card-text -->
                </div>
            </div><!-- end card -->
        </div><!-- end column -->
    </div><!-- end row -->
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, this results in multiple columns that stick around, no matter how narrow my browser window gets. The layout should respond and fall back to a single column on very narrow windows.